# Cannot connect to internet unless I disable packet forwarding on a mac

Tags: networking, macos, vpn

After using a VPN client (hide.me) it seems that I cannot connect to the internet unless I run this command:

`sudo pfctl -d`

As per their documentation here: https://hide.me/en/knowledgebase/how-to-restore-internet-connectivity-on-macos/

The problem is that I have to run this after each restart. I'm not sure how to clear this or permanently disable it? Should I be disabling it?

My mac firewall is set to off.

Comment: Which VPN client? What happens when you uninstall it?

Comment: That's not just packet forwarding, that's also the firewall. Most users who want the firewall off turn it off in System Preferences. Look at both your firewall settings as well as your Internet Sharing settings, as Internet Sharing uses the `pf` (packet filter) subsystem as well.

Comment: VPN client: hide.me | 
Mac Firewall is off

Comment: I uninstalled the VPN client but the problem persists

Comment: according to my research, I could only found the command you provided to Turn off macOS native packet filter firewall. Maybe you can try to use a script to run this command automatically each time you reboot.